# Aligning an html element to the right and the text written from right to left

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I was trying to make the avatar align to the left and the text connecting the right side and when text gets longer it will write from right to left.

```
<div class="row" style="display: flex; justify-content: right;">
     <h5 class="col-3 my-4" vertical-align="middle" style="color:#f2f2f2; font-family: Sarina; margin: 0">letsVibe</h5>
     <div class="col-9" style="float: right; margin-left: auto; margin-right:0px;">
         <div id="my-user-profile" class="row">
             <p id="my-username" style="color: #f2f2f2; font-family: Sansation-Bold; margin: 1.5rem; padding-left: 2.5rem;">MrRobot</p>
             <img class="profile-avatar" src="./images/avatar.png" alt="profile-avatar" style="width: 25%; height: auto; border:none;">
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA4Ri.png)

Comment: Please explain your objective?

Comment: I want the img element and the p to be on the right side. while the h5 element is on the left

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; width: 100%; justify-content: space-between;">
     <h5 style="font-family: Sarina; margin: 0">letsVibe</h5>
         <div id="my-user-profile" style="display: flex;justify-content: flex-end;align-items: center;">
             <p id="my-username" style="margin: 1.5rem; padding-left: 2.5rem;">MrRobot</p>
             <img class="profile-avatar" src="img_girl.jpg" alt="profile-avatar" style="width: 25%; height: auto; border:none;">
         </div>
</div>
```

If you don't wanna justify the image and p to right, just remove justify-content: flex-end;

Comment: @user10944910 If this answer is good, can you please close the question. Just click the tick mark beside the answer.